# Unable to find php8.0-fpm.sock in /run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock, Nginx Web Server

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, unix-sockets

I'm currently listening for TCP sockets in my Nginx Web Server, but for some reasons I'd like to listen to my UNIX-domain sockets. The issue is I'm unable to find `php8.0-fpm.sock` in both `/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock` and `/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock` paths. When I run `ls /run/php`, it shows only `php8.0-fpm.pid`.

`systemctl status php8.0-fpm` confirms that it is installed and running correctly:

```
php8.0-fpm.service - The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager

     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php8.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor pr /php8.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-10-30 03:03:54 EDT; 20min ago

       Docs: man:php-fpm8.0(8)

    Process: 282214 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper install /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 80 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

   Main PID: 282200 (php-fpm8.0)

     Status: "Processes active: 0, idle: 2, Requests: 7, slow: 0, Traffic: 0req/sec"

      Tasks: 3 (limit: 4621)

     Memory: 67.5M

     CGroup: /system.slice/php8.0-fpm.service
             ├─282200 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)

             ├─282212 php-fpm: pool www

             └─282213 php-fpm: pool www

Oct 30 03:03:54 127.0.0.1localhost systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Promd[1]: Starting The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager...

Oct 30 03:03:54 127.0.0.1localhost systemd[1]: Started The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Procmd[1]: Started The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to find it with.

```
find / -name "*fpm.sock"
```

Comment: Strangely they are on `/etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock` and
`/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/php-fpm.sock`? Should I use one of those?

Comment: Was there any dramatic change in PHP 8.0, that I'm missing?

Comment: you can change the fpm socket location by changing the ```lesten``` file path in ```/etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf```
By default the listen is set to ```lesten=/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose it :

> netstat -pluntx |grep php

Option -x in netstat is looking for all socket listen